# DJI Mavic Pro 2 drone in Webots nosedives at high speeds

Tags: ros2, webots

I am using the webots_ros2_mavic package found [here](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots_ros2/tree/master/webots_ros2_mavic) to simulate a drone in Webots. The drone is controlled by publishing a simple Twist message with linear and angular velocity components.

I noticed that when sending commands that are high speeds (such as a value of 5 or greater) to the linear velocity component of the Twist message, the drone tilts forwards when flying. As a result it starts descending/nosediving as it is also flying forwards. I understand that this also happens in real life with real drones.

Is there a way to eliminate this effect in given the code in this package? There is a file called `mavic_driver.py` in this package which implements a PID controller for the drone's movement. But I am not sure what (if anything at all) needs to be changed to achieve this effect.

I have tried tweaking some of the PID parameters in the `mavic_driver.py` file but I could not determine which ones, if any, need to be changed.

Setup: Ubuntu 22.04, ROS2 Humble, Webots 2023a